# WPF how to check Geometry intersections when transformations is applied?

Tags: c#, wpf, path, intersection, collision

I have few canvas objects with random size and applied RenderTransform angle.
Inside canvas i have geometry object (lines).

I am using binding for width and height to forse path to fill parent canvas object.

[image]

```
<Path x:Name="gem2_Copy" Stretch="Fill" Stroke="Black" Opacity="0.345" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=canvas}" Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=canvas}">
            <Path.Data>
                 <PathGeometry>
                    <PathFigure IsClosed="True" IsFilled="True">
                        <LineSegment  Point="0,0">

                        </LineSegment>  
                        <LineSegment  Point="5,5">

                        </LineSegment>  
                        <LineSegment  Point="0,5">

                        </LineSegment>      
                    </PathFigure>
                </PathGeometry>     
            </Path.Data>

            </Path>
```

How to check that PathFigure is intersecting with other path geometry?
I have algoritm to check that lines are intersected but i cannot apply it because path points lines points is always:
0,0
5,5
0,5

And i need global coordinates. How can i convert path points to global coordinates and take into account that render transform angle is changed and path width and height is changed?

```
foreach (var figure in geom.Figures) 
{
     foreach (LineSegment segment in figure.Segments)
     { 
        // I have here 0,0;5,5;0,5
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Already found how to do main part:

```
    // Get scale transformation (find scale factor)
    var w = (gem2_Copy.ActualWidth / gem2_Copy.Data.Bounds.Width);
    var h = (gem2_Copy.ActualHeight / gem2_Copy.Data.Bounds.Height);
    var transform = new ScaleTransform(w, h);

    foreach (var figure in geom.Figures)
    {
      foreach (LineSegment segment in figure.Segments)
      {
        // Use scale transformation to change geometry points position.
        var scaled=transform.Transform(segment.Point);

        // Translate point to screen coordinates (including rotation)
        var onScreen = canvas.TranslatePoint(scaled, root);

        // Use line intersection formula
      }
    }
```

Code that can find intersection:

```
public static Vector? Intersects(Point a1, Point a2, Point b1, Point b2)
    {
        Vector b = a2 - a1;
        Vector d = b2 - b1;
        var bDotDPerp = b.X * d.Y - b.Y * d.X;

        if (bDotDPerp == 0)
            return null;

        Vector c = b1 - a1;
        var t = (c.X * d.Y - c.Y * d.X) / bDotDPerp;
        if (t < 0 || t > 1)
        {
            return null;
        }

        var u = (c.X * b.Y - c.Y * b.X) / bDotDPerp;
        if (u < 0 || u > 1)
        {
            return null;
        }

        return new Vector(a1.X, a1.Y) + t * b;
    }
```